# JSP form action disabled: after adding Jquery Validation plugin. Need help on this

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jsp

I created a form which will get input(like Student Name) , then submit button this name will pass to servlet as get method and works fine.

Post that I tried form validation using external jquery plugin, even that also worked fine. But the submit action got disabled.

```js
##### Validation.js##
$(function(){
 jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    debug: true,
    success: "valid"
  });
 $("#myform").validate({
  rules:{
   
   StudentName:{
    required:true,
    minlength: 5,
       maxlength: 40
    
   }
   
  }
  
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/Validation.js"></script>
<form id="myform" action="addStudentContollerServlet" method="get">
   <input type="hidden" name="command" value="ADD"/>
   <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td><label>StudentName :</label></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="StudentName" id="StudentName"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td><label></label></td>
       <td><input type="submit" value="Save"  class="save" /></td>
      </tr>
      
    </tbody>
   </table>
</form>
```

Comment: So..What did you tried?

Comment: @Muthukumar Please edit your question instead of posting answers...

Comment: @Muthukumar what are you doing you are ruin terms here

Comment: **You are NEVER supposed to post question addenda as answers**.   If you were paying attention, you would have read a big warning message telling you this.   You are supposed to use the EDIT link above to fix your original question instead.

Answer (score -1):

Found the answers:

```
 by adding the below snippet it worked.
```

```js
$('#myform').submit(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   if( $(this).valid() ) {
     $(this).unbind('submit');}
     
     
 });
```

Comment: Not only are you not supposed to be posting questions as answers, how do you expect the Code Snippets feature to work when the HTML is posted in one place and the JavaScript is posted in some other place?  **[Please read the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how to use this site before mucking around.**